# Shiny - display image next to widget for info pop-up

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to display an information (i) image next to a `selectInput` control in Shiny, which the user can click on to display some more extensive help about the control.

I can use `renderImage` to display the image and `modalDialog` combined with a click event on the rendered image to display the information. HOWEVER what I am unable to achieve is to put the image next to the widget. By default it displays below the widget. Theoretically I could put the image in a new column but this leads to far too much space between the widget and the image.

Is there any way around this? Alternatively, can I display the image in the control's label while still allowing it to be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the property `display:inline-block` the elements that should appear next to each other. Working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(style='display: inline-block;',
      selectInput('input','Input: ', choices=LETTERS[1:10])
  ),
  img(src='https://www.zorro.com/wp-content/uploads/cc_resize/005-1200x542.jpg',height='100px',style='display: inline-block;'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image]

---

Furthermore, you can use e.g. `margin-left:100px` in the image style to control the space between the elements.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so very much. Extra kudos for using Zorro.